# Make compound strings in list based on list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have the following lists:

```
lst_a=['a1 b1 c1','a2 b2','a3 b3 c3 d3']
lst_b=['a1','b1','c1','d','e','a3','b3','c3','d3','f','a2', 'b2']
```

The output in lst_b would make compound strings based on lst_a like follows:

```
result=['a1 b1 c1','d','e','a3 b3 c3 d3','f','a2 b2']
```

How can I make the list b to change independent items to compound items based on lst_a?

Comment: They are not lists.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how you get from the first snippet to the second.  It looks like you want the grouping from `lst_a`, with the sorting from `lst_b`, and then also any leftover elements from `lst_b`?  Or is it sufficient to simply take `lst_b` and group by the second character if it exists?

Comment: The lst_a includes just compound strings for each item and list_b includes all items as single strings. Then, result has compound string for items which exist in lst_a and also includes the item from lst_b if it is a single item instead of compound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Iterate through `lst_b`, and concatenate its elements until the result is no longer a prefix of an element of `lst_a`.**

```py
lst_a=['a1 b1 c1','a2 b2','a3 b3 c3 d3']
lst_b=['a1','b1','c1','d','e','a3','b3','c3','d3','f','a2', 'b2']

r = []
current = lst_b[0]
for w in lst_b[1:]:
  new_current = ' '.join([current, w])
  if new_current in (v[:len(new_current)] for v in lst_a):
    current = new_current
  else:
    r.append(current)
    current = w
r.append(current)

print(r)
```

**Output:** `['a1 b1 c1', 'd', 'e', 'a3 b3 c3 d3', 'f', 'a2 b2']`

Remark: since you only gave this very particular example of `lst_a` and `lst_b`, it is impossible for me to say whether this algorithm would conform or not conform with what you would expect for a generalization of your problem to other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a bit ugly but should work.

```
lst_a=['a1 b1 c1','a2 b2','a3 b3 c3 d3']
lst_b=['a1','b1','c1','d','e','a3','b3','c3','d3','f','a2', 'b2']

r = []
seps = 0
for i, ele in enumerate(lst_b):
    if seps == 0:
        f = [i for i in lst_a if i.startswith(ele)]
        if f:
            f = f[0]
            seps = f.count(" ")
            if " ".join(lst_b[i:i+seps+1]) == f:
                r.append(f)
                lst_a.remove(f)
            else:
                r.append(ele)
        else:
            r.append(ele)
    else:
        seps -= 1

    
# Out[68]: ['a1 b1 c1', 'd', 'e', 'a3 b3 c3 d3', 'f', 'a2 b2']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Andreas. The solution would not work because the order in lst_a and lst_b is important. For instance, if you change lst_a for `lst_a=['a1 c1','a2 b2','a3 b3 c3 d3']` would not catch that `a1c1` should not be considered because in `lst_b` there is  'a1','b1','c1'